# Get an information about song from apple music link

Tags: objective-c, apple-music

Apple suggests us a way to search items in apple music with affiliate linking. But, is it possible to get information about the song from a link. For example this link: https://itun.es/ua/qzPyfb?i=1164089149. I need to get information from this link, that I can use to search for the song, for example, in MPMediaLibrary.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have found the answer. The last numbers are product id. Taking that link https://itun.es/ua/qzPyfb?i=1164089149. Imagine that we already get from string last numbers.

```
 MPMediaLibrary *library = [MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary];
    [library addItemWithProductID:trackId completionHandler:^(NSArray<__kindof MPMediaEntity *> * _Nonnull entities, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) { 
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        } else {
            if ([entities count]) {
                for (MPMediaItem *item in entities) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", item.title);
                }
            } else {
                    NSLog(@"There is no track with this product Id. Bad link.");
            }
        }
    }];
```